# Credentials access problem

Tags: magento-1.9, access

My username and password correct, but not logged into magento back end or control panel, its return Access Denied.
[image]

Comment: I think your password should be expire. Try to Update it via db and check. Else check from db role of your admin user.

Comment: after bulk import images, product page not visible magento back end, so i did roles -> reset filters. right after i get access denied problem.

Comment: create new user from db and login with the new one then reset password and roles from admin for your existing one.

Comment: how can i do what you told

Comment: can you please come for a chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39888/chat-with-jeeva

Comment: are u their i am done with it please come to chat room

Comment: yes tell me how you did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39990/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-ashish-madankar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is on basis of chat with you it looks that your **admin_rule** table get clear it is not able to find a rule for your role.

For this you have to create entry in this table for your role which is in **admin_role** table. or else you can upload a backup of your old table if you have.

To make a user login 3 tables are taken into consideration whose relation are as follows.

**1) admin_user**

This table stores all data of user information like name, password,create date, active or not etc.

**2) admin_role**

This tables holds data of roles for users created in magento. for admin it is Administrators.This tables links to **admin_user** by user_id column.

**3) admin_rule**

This table is used to hold a data related to permission for a role. This table link to **admin_role**  table by role_id column.

In your case you can use https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BweKwHQ_asV2TnJreDZnRWszME0&usp=drive_web this link which will create above table with **admin as user name** and **admin@123 as password**

before importing this table take a backup of your existing tables.

after making login rest password for your user and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned MySql for generate new admin user :

```
LOCK TABLES `admin_role` WRITE , `admin_user` WRITE;

SET @SALT = "rp";
SET @USERID = "user_id"; /*Replace user_id with your user_id*/
SET @PASS = CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT( @SALT , "Password123") ), CONCAT(":", @SALT )); /*Replace Password123 with your password*/
SELECT @EXTRA := MAX(extra) FROM `admin_user` WHERE extra IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO `admin_user` (firstname,lastname,email,username,password,created,lognum,reload_acl_flag,is_active,extra,rp_token_created_at) 
VALUES ('Firstname','Lastname','email@example.com',@USERID,@PASS,NOW(),0,0,1,@EXTRA,NOW()); /*Replace Firstname,Lastname,Email with your details*/

INSERT INTO `admin_role` (parent_id,tree_level,sort_order,role_type,user_id,role_name) 
VALUES (1,2,0,'U',(SELECT user_id FROM `admin_user` WHERE username = @USERID),'Firstname'); /*Replace firstname with provided firstname on above insert*/

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Note : If you are using table prefix then please add your table prefix in each table before using this query.

Comment: same problem access denied